# R: delete blank spaces for matrix stored to a textfile

Tags: r, text, matrix

I just ran into a problem with my R script. The script is intended to change certain values and store these in a text-file (which is then passed to a pre-existing Fortran code for further analysis).

Imagine we have 4 different parameters, extracted from a list. We call the subset "parameters" with the following attributes:

1. number of apples
2. average volume of the apples in [cm³]
3. apples eaten by my neighbor
4. percentage of apples that are turned into juice

One setting could be:

```
> parameters
      num apple   volume   neighbor juice 
1      73          98.7       7     0.03
```

The data is extracted from a list and then, in order to apply all kinds of functions, converted to numeric:

```
parameters <- as.numeric(parameters)
```

In the end I need the values to be written in a textfile with one value per line, so I turn them into a matrix:

```
parameters <- as.matrix(parameters)
 > parameters
            [,1]
 [1,] 73.0000000
 [2,] 98.7000000
 [3,]  7.0000000
 [4,]  0.0030000
```

This is the exact way R writes the data to a text file then by calling:

```
 write.table(format(parameters,digits=7),"parameters.txt",col.names=F, row.names=F,quote=F)
```

So far so good. Now the Fortran script comes in and has a problem with [3,1]. Notice the blank space before the value (7.0) which is also present in the text file. If I manually delete the one blank space before number "7" Fortran works fine...if I don't, it will crash. Is there a way I can keep R from creating this space? It seems R tries to always have the decimal point at the exact same position for every line, but I need all values to be left alligned.

I tried converting the numbers to strings before writing them to a text file, but Fortran doesn't like that either (it turns a "3" into "0.0000003") and unfortunately I don't have access to that Fortran code. Converting the matrix into a data.frame didn't change anything either.

Hope you got my problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: According to `?format` using `format(parameters,digits=7,trim=TRUE)` should solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the format function that you are using there is an argument called "trim" to trim these blanks. I believe that might work for you. The exact code in your current situation is:

```
write.table(format(parameters,digits=7, trim = TRUE),"parameters.txt",col.names=F, row.names=F,quote=F)
```

I hope it works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for this simple but great answer!! It totally works :)